# Android adb command to get total contacts on device

Tags: android, adb

Can you please let me know if there is any adb command that can be used to find total number of contacts on device.
-thanks in advance,
Manju

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this does not require root and `sqlite`:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/phones/  --projection display_name:number:notes  # google contacts?

adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data --projection display_name:data1:data4:contact_id
```

Comment: I´m getting permission denial with that commands, "accessing provider:com.android.contactsjava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=12044, uid=10101"

Comment: Yet more compact: $ adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/phones/  --projection display_name:number | cut -f 3- -d " "

Answer (score 5):

There are a few `adb` commands that appear to work (as of on Android 10).

#### List the people in the contact list

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/people/
```

#### Count people in contact list

Assuming you have a bash shell (Linux, OSX, or Windows Subsystem for Linux), you can pipe the output of those commands to `wc -l` to get the count.

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/people/ | wc -l
```

Other interesting commands include:

#### List the phone numbers

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/phones/
```

#### List the groups

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/groups/
```

#### List group membership

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/groupmembership/
```

#### List organizations

```sh
adb shell content query --uri content://contacts/organizations/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null, null,null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    listName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
    listContactId.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
    if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {                
        Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)),null, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            listMobileNo.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex("DATA1")));
        } 
        pCur.close();
    } else
        listMobileNo.add("");
}
```

## update

---

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db <PATH TO PASTE THE DATABASE>
```

after retreiving the DB use SQLite Browser to open it

Comment: is there any adb command available to get count of contacts on android device ?

Comment: phone not rooted !! permission denied !!                                                                                                                                              c:\>adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db .
failed to copy '/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db' to './contacts2.db': Permission denied

Comment: you have to root then

Answer (score 2):

To count all contacts on the device:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts | wc -l
```