# How to store contacts from adb shell? [Android]

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, android-debugging

I came across the following: [Android adb command to get total contacts on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927731/android-adb-command-to-get-total-contacts-on-device)

Im at a point where my display isnt working. The command given above just displays my contatcts. Is there some way I can convert it to a backup file? So that I can restore it on my spare android phone?

Comment: As you asking for an adb solution I assume your device is not synced with Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether creating a backup file manually is possible (you would need to know how data is stored and read by the contacts app in .vcf files), but if you simply want to extract and save the data:

Simply use ">" sign, eg.:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts | wc -l > Contacts.txt
```

or (if you want to specify a path)

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts | wc -l > /home/pi/Desktop/Contacts.txt
```

This will create a file named Contacts (with a .txt format) that holds the command output

Comment: Why `| wc -l`? That will eliminate the content and replace it with the number of lines

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. 
I got an error saying wc is not a cmdlet function. So I used 
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts > /home/pi/Desktop/Contacts.txt
and I got the file as I wanted!

Comment: Is there a possibility to put those contacts into another phone (I used the upper line for export with end "... >> file", but there is no "...<<" syntax :( )?

Answer (score 0):

To display contact columns and extract them :

`adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts > /home/enokseth/contacts_columns.txt`

return a column index in a brut text file.

format as JSON with `awk`:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts | \
awk -F '|' '{
  split($1, id_parts, ", ");
  printf "{";
  for (i = 1; i <= length(id_parts); i++) {
    split(id_parts[i], sub_parts, "=");
    key = sub_parts[1];
    value = sub_parts[2];
    gsub(/^ */, "", key);   # delete space in start of space 
    gsub(/ *$/, "", value); # delete space at end 
    printf "\"%s\":\"%s\"", key, value;
    if (i < length(id_parts)) {
      printf ",";
    }
  }
  printf "}\n";
}' > /home/enokseth/osint-adb/contacts.json
```

and last command consit to find raw_user to extract number :

`adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones --projection data1 --where "raw_contact_id=1"`

return :

`Row: 0 data1=07 45 23 65 12`

and for all constact